# how to pass a parameter with a link to an exe file from a html page

Tags: html

I have the following requirement. I have a link in a HTML page and on clicking it I need to pass a parameter alongwith the link to a .exe file. This is so that the .exe file opens up with the parameter provided.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The best way to run exe from a web page with support on all browser is to use **URL protocols**. You have to register custom URL protocol of client's machine. During registration you are actually linking the exe with you custom protocol name. Let's say it was `myprot`. Now in you hyperlink you can sepcify -

```
<a href="myprot:anythinghere">my exe link</a>
```

You can now pass anything after the `myprot:` and request that from the argument in your application

See - [Registering a custom url protocol](http://www.openwinforms.com/run_exe_from_javascript.html)